# Do I need a null check for HttpRequest.Files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm wondering, if I have

```
HttpRequest thisRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

and I'm trying to access a file like

```
if(thisRequest.Files.Count > 0)
{
   // ...
}
```

do I also need to first check whether `thisRequest.Files` is non-`null` or is that guaranteed?

I can't tell by reading the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx so maybe my question is more about how I can find the answer to my question.

Comment: From the documentation I would take it as no check is required and "*the collection* of files uploaded by the client" is always returned. Most (MSDN) documentation does - and it certainly *should* - mention an explicit null-return case.

Comment: On the other hand, the MSDN Documentation for [SynchronizationContext.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) does not mention that it can return null ([but it can](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx)) .. *sigh*, there I go countering my own statements :}

Comment: No. Just check the count is enough.

Comment: FWIW, C#6.0 would allow "not caring" by using `this.Request.Files?.Count > 0` - see [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to. All `HttpRequest` collections are initialized and empty in the beginning.

Comment: Where can I find documentation confirming that?

Comment: There isn't any, its solely from experience, but, you can check the source here, it does set all collections to empty ones each one at a point or another http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,3746181a8c06fa24